# Form Validation with ngx-stripe 11.0.0

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

Reading the ngx-stripe API I could not find a way to validate the stripe elements before enabling my 'pay' button (for example, credit card info is complete).
Can someone provide a sample code fragment?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You'd want to use the 'change' event listener on Stripe Elements to see if the input looks ["complete"](https://stripe.com/docs/js/element/events/on_change?type=cardElement#element_on_change-handler-complete).

```
cardElement.on('change', function(event) {
  if (event.complete) {
    // enable payment button
  } else if (event.error) {
    // show validation to customer
  }
});
```

Comment: Or the equivalent angular way which is: "<ngx-stripe-card ...                   (change)="cardChange($event)"...